# How to use TO_DATE to update a DATE field in SQL to a PM time

Tags: sql, oracle

What I need to do is pretty simple.

I just need to update a DATE field in SQL to a PM time.

Only thing is, if I use the TO_DATE function to update to an AM time, no problem...

```
TO_DATE('2021-09-30 11:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

However if I try to do the same thing to set to a PM time using military time...

```
TO_DATE('2021-09-30 23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

It says that the hour has to be between 1 and 12.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlqr/Format-Models.html#GUID-19B927AA-5567-438C-BD06-86C4E2B5F4F6), in order to convert a time in 24 hour format, you need to use `HH24`. When you use just `HH`, Oracle assumes the time to be in AM/PM format, i.e. that the number must be between 1 and 12.

So you need to change your code to the following

```sql
TO_DATE('2021-09-30 23:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e60760f625461994472b9bf8e08764be)